# How to create customized chapter heading in a Dynamic Document R and knitr

Tags: r, latex, customization, knitr, r-markdown

I´m not a `LaTex` user...actually started learning something about it as consequence of dynamic document I´m working with for a book document class I´m writing in `R` and `knitr`.

I´ve tried to customize the chapter headings, but meanwhile I did not get....I found the way to do this by LaTex (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73421/how-to-create-specific-chapter-style-in-book-documentclass) however I´m not knowing how to address by `RMardkown`.

Does anybody could help me with that? How can I arrange the below `LaTex` commands to be triggered by `RMarkdown` (by `.sty` file?) or something similar way to customize the chapter heading in output pdf?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

Thanks

Fabio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the stuff you want in the header, except the `documentclass` line, in a seperate tex file (I use `header.tex` below). You can then specify in the header of your R-markdown file that you want to include this file in the header. The `documentclass` van also be set in the header of your R-markdown file. More info on this can be found on the [rstudio site.](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html)

Below an example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
documentclass: book
---

\chapter{Introduction}


Section
=======

This is an R Markdown document.
```

`header.tex` looks like:

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

Comment: van der Lann: Thanks a lot! I worked. I had tried in a similar way, which was falling. But following your answer, it worked well